# Fetch file metadata (ie. photo title)

Tags: file-uploads, grid, image, files

I have a simple code:

```
{portfolio_photo}
    {portfolio_photo:file:fhd_c}
    {title}
{/portfolio_photo}
```

Line 1 renders the image, and I need image title to be rendered also (Line 2) (from file's meta), but whatever tag I try, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thx

Comment: did you try {portfolio_photo:file:title} ?

Comment: Is this inside a grid field?